# PySpark - rename key names in JSON stored as string column in CSV file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to update key name in my json stored as string column  and save it back as string type column. I am reading such columns from my csv & storing back as csv.

This is how my input csv looks.

```
candidate_email,transactions
cust2@email.com,"[{'transaction_id':'12', 'transaction_amount':'$23.43'},{'transaction_id':'15', 'transaction_amount':'$723.41'}]"
cust1@email.com,"[{'transaction_id':'10', 'transaction_amount':'$55.99'},{'transaction_id':'11', 'transaction_amount':'$20.46'},{'transaction_id':'13', 'transaction_amount':'$5.89'},{'transaction_id':'14', 'transaction_amount':'$35.61'}]"
```

I want to replace `transaction_id` key with `id` and `transaction_amount` with `amount` in my json and save it back as csv.

```
input_df = spark.read.csv('transactions/*.csv', header='true', inferSchema = True)
input_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- candidate_email: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- transactions: string (nullable = true)

input_df.show(10, False)
# +-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |candidate_email|transactions                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
# +-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |cust2@email.com        |[{'transaction_id':'12', 'transaction_amount':'$23.43'},{'transaction_id':'15', 'transaction_amount':'$723.41'}]                                                                                                            |
# |cust1@email.com        |[{'transaction_id':'10', 'transaction_amount':'$55.99'},{'transaction_id':'11', 'transaction_amount':'$20.46'},{'transaction_id':'13', 'transaction_amount':'$5.89'},{'transaction_id':'14', 'transaction_amount':'$35.61'}]|
# +-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I replace my keys to get following output?

```
output_df.show(10,False)
# +---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |candidate_email|transactions                                                                                                                |
# +---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |cust1@email.com|[{'id':'10', 'amount':'$55.99'},{'id':'11', 'amount':'$20.46'},{'id':'13', 'amount':'$5.89'},{'id':'14', 'amount':'$35.61'}]|
# |cust2@email.com|[{'id':'12', 'amount':'$23.43'},{'id':'15', 'amount':'$723.41'}]                                                            |
# +---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: both columns are string type columns.

```
output_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- candidate_email: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- transactions: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: why not just do regexp_replace: `df.withColumn("transactions", regexp_replace("transactions", "transaction_", "")).show()`

Comment: you're right but I am thinking of something with UDF by where I can use json python module to do something more with key-pairs. Also, regex will replace every occurrence of ```transaction``` but I want to change some specific keys with unique names.

Comment: another way is to use from_json + to_json to change the key-name in case there is no explicit pattern between the original names and the expected names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`from_json`** to read transactions column as `array(struct...)` then cast to the required field names.

- then **`explode + to_json + groupBy + collect_list`** to get required json.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|candidate_email|transactions                                                                                                    |
#+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|cust2@email.com|[{'transaction_id':'12', 'transaction_amount':'$23.43'},{'transaction_id':'15', 'transaction_amount':'$723.41'}]|
#+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

st=ArrayType(StructType([StructField("transaction_id", StringType()),StructField("transaction_amount", StringType())]))

df.withColumn("jsn",from_json(col("transactions"),st).cast("array<struct<id:string,amount:string>>")).\
selectExpr("*","explode(jsn)").\
select("*","col.*").\
drop(*drop_cols).\
selectExpr("candidate_email","to_json(struct(id,amount)) as trans").\
groupBy("candidate_email").\
agg(collect_list("trans").alias("transactions")).\
show(10,False)

#+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
#|candidate_email|transactions                                                   |
#+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
#|cust2@email.com|[{"id":"12","amount":"$23.43"}, {"id":"15","amount":"$723.41"}]|
#+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```